# How do i include a senderId to my script below bearing in mind that the sms gateways string is $from instead of $senderId

Tags: php, sms, integration, gateway

i need help including a senderID from the sms gateway provider. The code below works but the gateway introduced a $from string which pulls the SenderID, I need help to include on this script.

I modified: `$data = array("username" =>$username, "message" =>$msg, "from" =>$from, "to" => $to);` but no luck.

I would appreciate your help please

```
function  africastalking_send_sms($to,$msg)
{
    $api_key=$this->user;
    $username=$this->phone_number;

    try {
        $url = 'http://api.africastalking.com/version1/messaging';
        $data = array("username" =>$username, "message" =>$msg, "to" => $to);

        $ch=curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json","Apikey:{$api_key}"));
        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close($ch);

        $response=json_decode($response,TRUE);
        $message_info['id'] = isset($response['SMSMessageData']['Recipients'][0]['messageId']) ? $response['SMSMessageData']['Recipients'][0]['messageId'] : "";
        $message_info['status'] = isset($response['SMSMessageData']['Recipients'][0]['status']) ? $response['SMSMessageData']['Recipients'][0]['status'] : "Error";

        return $message_info;
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        $message_info['id'] = "";
        $message_info['status' ] ='error in config';

        return $message_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I modified: `$data...`* - that array is in a function (or public class method) so just adding an index of `'from' => $from` isn't going to work because `$from` is not in the function scope, you'd need to pass it in.

Comment: It's on CodeIgniter, the modification caused some errors